How to properly implement zkSNARKs in Solidity?
I have been reading a lot about Zk-SNARKs, and most of the guides, tutorials and examples use Zokrates toolbox that is pretty complete for generating proofs of computation to verifying those proofs in Solidity.
The main problem is that Zokrates' Github repository does not have too much activity in the last years, and any in the last 6 months.
In the beginning of the repository they clearly state the following:
This is a proof-of-concept implementation. It has not been tested for production.
They also have a Remix plugin that it's also in Beta.
Conclusion:
It seems that Zokrates is the most advanced ZkSnarks tool in the EVM ecosystem. However it seems to be in a beta mode, and with little development in the last years. But we had Tornado Cash working from several years ago, properly implementing ZkSnarks.
So, why the available technology is so pretty advanced, when there have been some successful projects implementing it in the past?
